# Page redirection when no network in ionic3

Tags: ionic2, ionic3

I have implemented one application in which the page will redirect to a page showing “no network” when the user gone offline. I have successfully implemented that. App navigates to the below screen when there is no network.In the below scenario the logic fails,’

Application fails to redirect to the " no network page " when the user opens the application for the first time or after kill during offline. In this case application launches the default root page say LoginPage.
Please find the logic below.

### NetworkCheckProvider.ts

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Network } from '@ionic-native/network';
import { Events } from "ionic-angular";

export enum ConnectionStatusEnum {
    Online,
    Offline
}    
@Injectable()
export class NetworkCheckProvider {

 private previousStatus;
    constructor(private eventCtrl: Events,
                private netWork:Network) {
        this.previousStatus = ConnectionStatusEnum.Online;
    }
    public initializeNetworkEvents(): void {
        this.netWork.onDisconnect().subscribe(() => {
            if (this.previousStatus === ConnectionStatusEnum.Online) {
                this.eventCtrl.publish('network:offline');
            }
            this.previousStatus = ConnectionStatusEnum.Offline;
        });
        this.netWork.onConnect().subscribe(() => {
            if (this.previousStatus === ConnectionStatusEnum.Offline) {
                this.eventCtrl.publish('network:online');
            }
            this.previousStatus = ConnectionStatusEnum.Online;
        });
    }
}
```

### app.component.ts

```
initializeApp() {
  this.platform.ready().then(() => {
  this.statusBar.styleDefault();
  this.splashScreen.hide();
  this.networkCheck();
  this.netWorkCheck.initializeNetworkEvents();
  }

networkCheck() {
    this.events.subscribe('network:online', () => {
        this.generic.showToast("Network Available");
        console.log('network connected!');
    });

    this.events.subscribe('network:offline', () => {
        debugger;
        if(this.nav.getActive().name!='NoInternetPage' || this.nav.getActive().name==null)
            this.nav.push('NoInternetPage');
    });
}
}
```

Please correct me if there is any mistake in my code. Also is there is any way to disable all click events during offline?

Thanks and Regards
Anand Raj